# UIViewController not showing background after segue

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard, segue, uivewcontroller

Storyboard:

[image]

Simulator before segue with view (which is connected to a tab bar controller) showing correct background:

[image]

A tap on any of the icons causes a push segue but the background is white, when it should be blue:
[image]

I'm using AQGridview and the code for the segue is:

```
-(void)gridView:(AQGridView *)gridView didSelectItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"mySegue" sender:self];
}
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was something rather stupid but I'll explain it because it's the type of thing I can imagine happening to anyone else who is as daft as me. (There has to be *someone* as daft as me...)

I'd earlier added a webView to to the viewDidLoad method of the destination ViewController. The default colour of the webView is white and it was overlaid on top of the background colour, so I couldn't see it.

Removed the code referring to the webView and all was well again.

Yes, I'm feeling rather foolish now.

Answer (score 1):

Did you set the seque Identifier?

[image: Did you set the seque Identifier?]

Comment: Thanks, yes. It's named `mySegue`. If I change it or delete it, the program crashes with an "unknown identifier" error.